# How can I parse html table inside a script respecting merged cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This header is contained in a js file https://www.portaldefinancas.com/js-tx-ctb/th-cdib.js

[image]

```
document.write(""),document.write('</p></caption><thead><tr><th rowspan="4">M&ecirc;s de<br>Refer&ecirc;ncia</th><th colspan="7">Taxas - %</th></tr><tr>    <th rowspan="3">Mensal</th><th colspan="4">Anualizada</th><th colspan="2">Acumulada</th></tr><tr>   <th colspan="2">Ano de<br>252 dias<br> &uacute;teis</th><th colspan="2">Ano de<br>365/366 dias<br>corridos</th><th rowspan="2">No ano</th><th rowspan="2">Em <br>12 meses</th></tr><tr><th>Dias</th><th>    Taxa</th><th>Dias</th><th>  Taxa</th></tr></thead><tbody>');
```

How can I parse the headers respecting the merged rows and merged columns. The script I use today is

```
function getHeaders(url) {
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  source = source.split('document')[2]
  var table = '<table><tr><th ' + source.match(/(?<=<th ).*(?=th>)/g) + 'th></tr></table>'
  table=table.replace(/&ecirc;/g,'ê').replace(/&uacute;/g,'ú').replace(/<br>/g,'\n')
  var doc = XmlService.parse(table);
  var rows = doc.getDescendants().filter(function(c) {
    var element = c.asElement();
    return element && element.getName() == "tr";
  });
  var data = rows.slice(0).map(function(row) {
    return row.getChildren("th").map(function(cell) {
      return cell.getValue();
    });
  });
  return data; 
}
```

but it doesn't respect merged areas. Thanks for any help !

Comment: Of course it can be parsed via script and then be recreated on a spreadsheet via script. But I'm sure the code that will able to parse and recreate any given table will be monstrous. If you have just one table, it's would be much easier just to make a new spreadsheet with the same design and placeholders, get texts via `getHeaders()` function and then replace the placeholders with the texts via another simply function.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, this is what I did, but I would like to get a standalone script as it could be repeated in the future. Here is my project https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18yhDYr91ORrofV20FMWYmYnwwnGK0QaQguG9uLdP5co/copy

Comment: Well. It seems to me like a quite big task. Unless someone had done it already.

Comment: If no one has already done this task, I will ... `It always seems impossible until it's done.` (Nelson Mandela)

Comment: I'd use a template for the headers and merged cells and load the data with a 2d array and if I have to modify the template to make the code easier I would do that also.

Comment: I am developing a script with `.getAttribute ('colspan').getValue()` and `.getAttribute ('rowspan').getValue()`. I don't want to merge cells in worksheet, but place them from bottom to top (if colspan ... the last row gets the value). Thanks in advance because I won't have much time for the next few days. It's only for me an intellectual exercise and a curiosity I have already done in excel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution, example with url = `https://www.portaldefinancas.com/js-tx-ctb/th-cdib.js`

```
function getHeaders(url) {
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  source = source.split('document')[2]
  var table = '<table><tr><th ' + source.match(/(?<=<th ).*(?=th>)/g) + 'th></tr></table>'
  table=table.replace(/&ecirc;/g,'ê').replace(/&uacute;/g,'ú').replace(/<br>/g,'\n')
  var doc = XmlService.parse(table);
  var rows = doc.getDescendants().filter(function(c) {
    var element = c.asElement();
    return element && element.getName() == "tr";
  });
  var n=0
  var data=[]
  rows.slice(0).map(function(row) {data[n++]=[]})
  n=0
  rows.slice(0).map(function(row) {
    row.getChildren("th").map(function(cell) {
      try{nbcols = cell.getAttribute('colspan').getValue()}catch(e){nbcols = 1}
      try{nbrows = cell.getAttribute('rowspan').getValue()}catch(e){nbrows = 1}
      var value = cell.getValue()
      r=0
      var free=0
      while(r<nbrows*1){
        c=0
        while(c<nbcols*1){
          while(data[n+r][free]!=null){free++}
          data[n+r][free]=(value)
          value=''
          c++
        }
        r++
      }
    });
    n++
  });
  return (data); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since intellectual exercises is my my drug of choice... I can't help it. Here is the possible solution. It works to a degree but it shows little the traits of lofty style of coding:

```
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data  = getHeaders();
  data      = handle_rowspans(data);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}

function getHeaders(url) {
  // var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  // source = source.split('document')[2]

  var source = `<thead><tr><th rowspan="4">M&ecirc;s de<br>Refer&ecirc;ncia</th><th colspan="7">Taxas - %</th></tr><tr>    <th rowspan="3">Mensal</th><th colspan="4">Anualizada</th><th colspan="2">Acumulada</th></tr><tr>   <th colspan="2">Ano de<br>252 dias<br> &uacute;teis</th><th colspan="2">Ano de<br>365/366 dias<br>corridos</th><th rowspan="2">No ano</th><th rowspan="2">Em <br>12 meses</th></tr><tr><th>Dias</th><th>    Taxa</th><th>Dias</th><th>  Taxa</th></tr></thead><tbody>`;

  source = handle_colspans(source);

  table = '<table><tr><th ' + source.match(/(?<=<th ).*(?=th>)/g) + 'th></tr></table>';
  table = table.replace(/&ecirc;/g, 'ê').replace(/&uacute;/g, 'ú').replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
  var doc = XmlService.parse(table);
  var rows = doc.getDescendants().filter(function (c) {
    var element = c.asElement();
    return element && element.getName() == "tr";
  });
  var data = rows.slice(0).map(function (row) {
    return row.getChildren("th").map(function (cell) {
      return cell.getValue();
    });
  });
  return data;
}

function handle_colspans(table) {
  return table.split('</tr>').map(r => add_cells_in_row(r)).join('</tr>');

  function add_cells_in_row(row) {
    var cells = row.split('</th>');
    for (var i in cells) {
      if (/colspan/.test(cells[i])) {
        var colspan = cells[i].replace(/.*colspan="(\d+).*/, '$1');
        cells[i] += '{col' + colspan + '}';
        cells[i] = [cells[i], ...(new Array(+colspan - 1).fill('<th>'))];
      }
      if (/rowspan/.test(cells[i])) {
        var rowspan = cells[i].replace(/.*rowspan="(\d+).*/, '$1');
        cells[i] += '{row' + rowspan + '}';
      }
    }
    return cells.flat().join('</th>')
  }
}

function handle_rowspans(array) {
  for (var row in array) {
    for (var col in array[row]) {
      if (/\{row/.test(array[row][col])) {
        var rowspan = array[row][col].replace(/.*\{row(\d+).*/s, '$1');
        for (var r = 1; r < rowspan; r++) array[+row + r].splice(col, 0, '')
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

It will get you the table like this:

[image]

Whrere `{row#}` and `{col#}` means how many cells or rows to the left or to the bottom you need to join to the current cell to recreate the original design. It could be the next dose of the intellectual exercises. :)

Comment: Wow! this was also one of my thoughts, to add extra cells when colspan and rowspan exist, I'll study the code because there is a lot of syntax that I don't know yet. I'm going to continue on my side by filling in a "mirror" with the merged cells to avoid writing the data inside (I'm not sure if that's understandable), but your code seems working fine. I will integrate it in the project.

Comment: How can I remove `cells[i] += '{row' + rowspan + '}'` ?

Comment: Add the line `array[row][col] = array[row][col].replace(/\{row\d+\}/, '');` in function `handle_rowspans(array)` between the lines `var rowspan = ...` and `for (var r = ...`